# When running a Grunt server, getting "cannot GET/" error in browser (angular app)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm trying to run an angular app with a Grunt server, and when I serve it up and navigate to it, the only thing it is displaying is "cannot GET/".

I am working on this app and it is my responsibility to get it to run for testing.

I looked in the gruntfile, and the 'base' option is set to 'public', which I can't find a corresponding folder to anywhere in the directory.

```
grunt.initConfig({
   connect: {
   server: {
     options: {
       port: 3001,
       base: 'public',
       keepalive: true
    }
  }
```

There are also a few instances of public cropping up later in the file, for instance:

```
templates: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= app.templates %>/',
      src: ['**/*.html'],
      dest: 'public/'
    }]
```

I don't know what to do!

I did try to change the base option to where the index.html file is located, and I stopped getting the "cannot GET/", but then the angular bindings were not working.

Comment: it sounds as though changing the `base:` solved the issue you are describing in this question, but created a different issue (angular bindings not working).  I think you might consider this issue closed, and open a new question describing the angular bindings, including any code and potentially any console errors you are receiving.

Comment: Perhaps, yeah. But I'm also wondering, maybe there's a reason it was written like that and was actually correct, but for some other work around that would make it work.